# How to find maximum number of repeated string in a string in a list of string in c#

Tags: c#, linq, computer-science

If we have a list of strings, then how we can find the list  of strings that have the maximum number of repeated symbol  by using LINQ.

```
       List <string> mylist=new List <string>();
        mylist.Add("%1");
        mylist.Add("%136%250%3"); //s0
        mylist.Add("%1%5%20%1%10%50%8%3"); // s1
        mylist.Add("%4%255%20%1%14%50%8%4"); // s2
        string symbol="%";
        List <string>  List_has_MAX_num_of_symbol=  mylist.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length ==max_num_of(symbol)).ToList();

//the result should be  a list of s1 + s2 since they have **8** repeated '%'
```

I tried

```
 var longest = mylist.Where(s => s.Length == mylist.Max(m => m.Length)) ;
```

this gives me only one string not both

Comment: Your question is not clear as it is written. Are you looking for the string(s?) which contain the maximum number of repeated character, or the count of the maximum repeat, or something else?

Comment: @jdphenix  it is updated now

Comment: Based on your comments to my answer, I have to assume that your explanation of what you need in your question is still incorrect. I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking. Please clarify if you can - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple solution, but not exactly efficient. Every element has the Count operation performed twice...

```
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        mylist.Add("%1");
        mylist.Add("%136%250%3"); //s0
        mylist.Add("%1%5%20%1%10%50%8%3"); // s1
        mylist.Add("%4%255%20%1%14%50%8%4"); // s2
        char symbol = '%';

        var maxRepeat = mylist.Max(item => item.Count(c => c == symbol));
        var longest = mylist.Where(item => item.Count(c => c == symbol) == maxRepeat);
```

It will return 2 strings:

"%1%5%20%1%10%50%8%3"

"%4%255%20%1%14%50%8%4"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that depends upon `SortedDictionary<,>` to get what you're after.

```
var mylist = new List<string> {"%1", "%136%250%3", "%1%5%20%1%10%50%8%3", "%4%255%20%1%14%50%8%4"};
var mappedValues = new SortedDictionary<int, IList<string>>();

mylist.ForEach(str =>
{
    var count = str.Count(c => c == '%');
    if (mappedValues.ContainsKey(count))
    {
        mappedValues[count].Add(str);
    }
    else
    {
        mappedValues[count] = new List<string> { str };
    }
});

// output to validate output
foreach (var str in mappedValues.Last().Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Here's one using LINQ that gets the result you're after.

```
var result = (from str in mylist
    group str by str.Count(c => c == '%')
    into g
    let max = (from gKey in g select g.Key).Max()
    select new
    {
        Count = max,
        List = (from str2 in g select str2)
    }).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Were you expecting one line of code or one method call? That won't happen.

Comment: Look this code gives me the first occurs :-

 var longest = mylist.Where(s => s.Length == mylist.Max(m => m.Length));

Comment: You didn't ask for the longest string, you asked for the one with the largest count of `%` characters.

Comment: Still waiting for more clever person :)

Comment: @JohnKanti We are also waiting here for clever questions. if you can't get it, you have to live with the one available,  like your question.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another implementation. I don't believe you'll find a trivial answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's my answer:

```
char symbol = '%';

var recs = mylist.Select(s => new { Str = s, Count = s.Count(c => c == symbol) });
var maxCount = recs.Max(x => x.Count);
var longest = recs.Where(x => x.Count == maxCount).Select(x => x.Str).ToList();
```

It is complicated because it has three lines (the `char symbol = '%';` line excluded), but it counts each string only once. EZI's answer has only two lines, but it is complicated because it counts each string twice. If you really want a one-liner, here it is:

```
var longest = mylist.Where(x => x.Count(c => c == symbol) == mylist.Max(y => y.Count(c => c == symbol))).ToList();
```

but it counts each string many times. You can choose whatever complexity you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can't assume that the `%` is always going to be the most repeated character in your list.  First, we have to determine what character appears the most in an individual string for each string.

Once we have the character and it maximum occurrence, we can apply `Linq` to the `List<string>` and grab the strings that contain the character equal to its max occurrence.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List <string> mylist=new List <string>();
        mylist.Add("%1");
        mylist.Add("%136%250%3");            
        mylist.Add("%1%5%20%1%10%50%8%3");   
        mylist.Add("%4%255%20%1%14%50%8%4"); 

        // Determine what character appears most in a single string in the list
        char maxCharacter = ' ';
        int maxCount = 0;
        foreach (string item in mylist)
        {
            // Get the max occurrence of each character
            int max = item.Max(m => item.Count(c => c == m));
            if (max > maxCount)
            {
                maxCount = max;
                // Store the character whose occurrence equals the max
                maxCharacter = item.Select(c => c).Where(c => item.Count(i => i == c) == max).First();
            }
        }

        // Print the strings containing the max character
        mylist.Where(item => item.Count(c => c == maxCharacter) == maxCount)
            .ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
%1%5%20%1%10%50%8%3
%4%255%20%1%14%50%8%4
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J13qfA)

Answer (score -3):

```
var newList = myList.maxBy(x=>x.Count(y=>y.Equals('%'))).ToList();
```

This should work. Please correct syntax if wrong anywhere and update here too if it works for you.

Comment: Care to provide reason for downvote, so that I can avoid that mistake from next time.

Comment: maybe for the unknown method `maxBy` ? BTW: OP wants 2 results not one as maxBy implies.